# passing get variables in joomla component

Tags: variables, joomla, get, components

I'm trying to build a simple joomla component what would show custom google search results based on it's API. How would I pass a get variable to a joomla component? Lets say I have already the basics what calls a custom view `index.php?option=com_google&view=google`, than I would like to pass `'q' $_GET` variable to it how should the url query string look like ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [HTTP request method `GET`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), works with the URL, so variables are always passed in the URL of the request.

To add `q` to your current URL you simply add `&q=SomeValue` where `SomeValue` has been appropriately [percent or URL encoded.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

**Joomla 1.5**

If you're using Joomla! 1.5 you can use [`JRequest`](http://docs.joomla.org/JRequest/1.5) to get the value of any variable whether submitted by `POST` or `GET`, see [this document on retrieving request variable](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_data_from_GET_and_POST_requests).

```php
$q = JRequest::getVar('q');
```

**Joomla 1.6+**

For Joomla! 1.6+ it is recommended to [use `JInput` to retrieve request data](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) as `JRequest` is depreciated, and for Joomla! 3.0+ you MUST use `JInput` as [`JRequest` has funcitonality removed](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1#JRequest) and will continue to disappear over the next few releases.

To use `JInput` you can either get the current object or use chaining through the current Joomla application to retrieve variables.

**Getting `JInput`**

```php
$jAp = JFactory::getApplication();  // Having the Joomla application around is also useful
$jInput = $jAp->input;  // This is the input object
$q = $jInput->get('q');  // Your variable, of course get() support other option...
```

**Using `JInput` via chaining**

```php
$jAp = JFactory::getApplication();  // Having the Joomla application around is also useful
$q = $jAp->input->get('q');  // Your variable
```

Comment: Think it's just worth pointing out here for completeness that even though it's deprecated most Joomla core components still use JRequest in Joomla 2.5 as JInput has known issues with magic quotes. JRequest does not. In Joomla 3.0 magic quotes is required to be turned off therefore there are no issues there!

Comment: @GeorgeWilson very true, but remember the magic quotes feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php (They are also OFF by default in PHP 5+ which most hosts are using these days).

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve GET vars in Joomla using:

```
$q = JRequest::getVar( 'q' );
```

This would work for a url string as per below:

```
index.php?option=com_google&view=google&q=some_variable
```